# .net6 unable to find an entry point named 'AdjustWindowRectExForDpi' in DLL user32.dll

Tags: c#

[image: Exception]

[image: WinformApp window]

winos: win7 ps1 x64

sdk: .NET SDK 6.0.100-preview.6.21355.2

app: winform app

ide: vs2022

Hello:

The winformapp work well at sdk(.NET 6.0.0 Preview 5 ).

Today i update de vs2022 and .NET 6.0.0 Preview 6.

When i add the Label Control in Winform and run the WinformApp in win7, it get the exception.

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`AdjustWindowRectExForDpi` is only supported on Windows 10 and above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectexfordpi

[.NET 6.0 is only supported on Windows 10 and above.](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md) So your options are to either build your application against .NET 5.0 or upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: The github show it's supported Windows Client（7 SP1(*), 8.1）.

Comment: Ah true it says so (why do they have two lines for that?). But apparently it is not. Possible that they didn't test whatever function you use there with Windows 7. .NET 6 is still beta, and Windows 7 is officially out of support.

Comment: @zxbe: The additional function call was introduced recently with this PR: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/pull/4797 It seems nobody was aware that this breaks Windows 7 compatibility.

Comment: (more detail link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416614/net6p6-unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-adjustwindowrectexfordpi-in-dll-us]

Answer (score 0):

In Forms, try to change the property `AutoScaleMode` to a value distinct to `Font`.

In Windows 8.1 this works.